# Build error upon facebook sdk installation

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, build.gradle, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am trying to install `Facebook SDK` to my react-native app which is being installed successfully, but when I try to run the app, it crashes with the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4' has different version for the compile (27.0.2) and runtime (27.1.1) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution
```

This error originates from another installed sdk (jumio) and more specifically from the file `application/node_modules/react-native-jumio-mobilesdk/android/build.gradle`

Can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/issues/1532 and https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14020

Answer (score 1):

When you have configurations clashing, you can force all projects to use a single build config
Add this to bottom of your `./android/build.gradle`

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 26 //or your preferred
                buildToolsVersion "26.0.3" // your preferred
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Added to the bottom of the file but still no luck.

Comment: I once had a problem with FBSDK similar to yours. 
Try this:
in your `.android/app/build.gradle` just below `dependencies` add this:
`configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1' //or your preferred
    }
}`

Comment: just to add, if you are on mac also run `cd android` then `./gradlew clean` after you edit the gradle files. If on windows just cd to android and run `gradlew clean`

Comment: LordKiz, thank you very much for your answers. I tried everything but still no success.
Whatever I do, I still get the same error.

What does this error mean? In what version should I switch and what is DependencyResolution?

Comment: It just says there are conflicting build dependencies. Have you used my answer and specified the main build tools you are using within your app?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had to update all the dependencies of `com.android.support` and not only the `com.android.support:v4:xx.x.x`. In my case it was

```
implementation com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2
api com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2

implementation com.android.support:design:27.0.2
implementation com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2
```

Thank you all for your answers and your time!

Comment: Great. Im glad you got this sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd android
gradlew clean
```

Delete node_modules folder then

```
npm install
```

Rebuild again an it should fix the error

Comment: Tried with gradle instead of gradlew because the latter could not be found, reinstalled all packages but still no luck.